# How does PrincipalContext know which LDAP server to use

Tags: vb.net, ldap

Using VB.NET, PrincipalContext without parameters. I understand that when ValidateCredentials is called it will use the credentials of the calling server, like in my case the account the ASP.NET app pool is running under. My question is, how does it know which LDAP server to check against? That isn't specified anywhere and just appears to work. The issue is, we're implementing a second LDAP server for testing purposes. Something tells me this will need new coding to include specific server details.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP server used, if the name parameter is not provided, is the one that the computer running your application (the IIS server) is joined too. As simple as that.

You can get the domain name any time using

```
Environment.GetUserDomainName
```

To implement a scenario where the domain to connect to might be different from the one by default, I would create an Appsetting, let's call it **Domain** for simplicity sake, then using the value of that setting (if found) to connect to the proper LDAP server.

If the value is blank or not available, then the default domain name provided by *Environment.GetUserDomainName* can be used instead.

```
using Context as new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,GetDomainName())
'Do something        
End Using
```

Here is the GetDomainName() function that check if the **Domain** appsetting exists and use it if found.

```
Public Function GetDomainName() As String

    Try
        Dim ConfigDomain As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Domain")
       If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigDomain) Then
            Return ConfigDomain
        Else
            Return Environment.UserDomainName
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Environment.UserDomainName
    End Try

End Function
```